# All but one fragments in activity are blank

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to build a user screen with several dynamically loaded parts, so I created an activity, added some other static content and 5 fragments in design view. For each of the fragments I created a new activity like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class fragmentX extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_registration_picker_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

The first fragment is visible all of the time and it works. There I have a webview and no issues.

Below I have 4 checkboxes and e.g. if the user clicks checkbox1 fragment2 will be displayed. I am able to show or hide the fragments using

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fr = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentX);
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.show(fr); // or ft.hide(fr);
ft.commit();
```

unfortunately the content of fragments 2-5 is not visible, there I only get a large blank space.

I also tried creating frameLayouts as placeholders and adding the fragments dynamically using

```
fr.add(R.id.myPlaceholderX,new fragmentX)
```

with the same result.

Any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Christian :)

Comment: BAD LOGIC, DEVELOPER! Start from scratch to learn how activities interact and then how fragments interact. After that implement your own logic by combining activity and fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I got a different solution that worked for me. I decided not to use fragments and instead have all the code within one activity. There I created a LinearLayout for each part that I want to hide. Each LL is invisible but additionally has a height of 0, otherwise the space would still be allocated.

When someone activates the checkbox I run

```
findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
LinearLayout llt = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
llt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

and if someone unchecks the checkbox I execute:

```
findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = llt.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 0;
llt.setLayoutParams(lp);
```